# Почему я не могу использовать Margin и Padding в своей разметке?

Tags: xamarin.forms

Когда запускаю приложение, меняю расположение текста в кнопке , или расположение кнопки в StackLayout

То разметка применяется, но когда я снова запускаю приложение, уже ругается на эти 2 свойства.

Я ещё согласен пренебречь свойством Margin, но как обойтись то без свойства Padding (если необходимо то поменять расположение текста в кнопке.)?

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="Librian.MainPage"
         
         NavigationPage.IconColor="Red">


<Grid >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="80"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="80"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>


    <Grid Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="Black">
        <Label Text="Grid.Row 0" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center"
               VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="30"> </Label>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="startFrame">
        <StackLayout Background="Yellow">
            <Button WidthRequest="64" HeightRequest="47" Padding="" Margin="10 0 0 0" Text="DDD" HorizontalOptions="Center"></Button>
        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="2" BackgroundColor="Blue">
        <Label Text="Grid.Row 2" TextColor="Wheat" HorizontalOptions="Center"
               VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="30"></Label>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Всё , решил проблему.  Xamarin не любит цифры через пробел, он это воспринимает лучше через запятую. Добавив запятые всё нормально. Жалко что Microsoft это не учли, и не сделали это ошибкой (что бы сам код подчёркивался, а так получается, в разметке правельно, а компилятор не воспринимает это)